How To Handle Lost Data Packets In TCP?
What are the proper ways to handle the TCP data packets lost during the transit?
I'm developing an instant messaging application with real-time chat feature. I rely mainly on TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) for instant messaging feature. However, even though my connection quality is good, when I send a message to the receiver, some of the messages are lost during the transit. Therefore, these lost messages cannot be sent to the clients. Here's my Node.js code that utilizes the net module for TCP protocol:
const net = require("net");
const clients = [];

net.createServer((socket) => {
    clients.push(socket);

    socket.on("close", () => clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1));

    socket.on("data", (data) => {
        clients.forEach((client) => client.write(JSON.parse(data.toString()).message));
    });
}).listen(8000, "185.255.95.248", () => console.log("TCP instance is running..."));

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, regards...

TCP doesn't lost packets, anticipating other question - how TCP recognizes connection interrupt? - you will get an exception/error while reading from channel.

@Ryan, then are packet losts caused by any connection interruption?

I'm not sure how it works in nodejs, but in TCP in general, you work with stream of bytes, you transmit/receive these chunks of bytes, it is impossible that you oversee some middle chunk of the message on the receive side, you just get error/exception while calling socket.read() operation. You should dive into nodejs documentation to find out how it works there.

Hm, tbh, it is hard to perceive nodejs as a backend here...

TCP handles lost packets automatically, retransmitting them as necessary. It ensures a reliable stream of data, applications don't have to worry about it.

" when I send a message to the receiver, some of the messages are lost during the transit." - the problem is very likely not TCP, but a wrong use of TCP.  A common problem is to blindly assume that a single send/write by the one side has a 1:1 matching recv/read by the peer. This assumptions is wrong - TCP provides a byte stream and not message semantics.
